# Glasses and Glass

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

Last year, I had been on an exchange trip to Britain where I ended up in a very confusing and embarrassing situation because of the following:
what / where is the difference in pronunciation between the plural form of glasses (vision aid) and glass (e.g. windows or a drinking vessel)?

Jakob

Comment: I can't speak to any particular dialect of British English, but American English, New York Metropolitan accent(s) don't have any difference that my ear can detect.

Comment: The plural form of the vision aides can be _pairs_ of glasses to avoid confusion. As for the word _glasses_ itself, it is the same word with the same pronunciation.

Comment: "Glass-ez" can be all of those. Pronunciation isn't as important as learning  to specify the 'type' of glass(es), i.e.; eye glasses, drinking glasses, wine glasses, beer glasses. Window glass is generally not pluralized. "This area holds our variety of window glass panes." Panes is plural and glass is singular

Comment: "The plural form of glasses" is pronounced "glarse-ez". "glass" is pronounced "glarse". The "ez" is the difference. If that's not what you meant to ask (and I suspect it's not), your question could do with rewording to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I'll just specify the type of glasses I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Glasses* is pronounced (British English) the same whether it refers to spectacles, drinking vessels or types of glass.

It's not impossible for this to lead to confusion, for example if you'd left your spectacles on the table while collecting washing up and asked someone to hand you the glasses. You'd have to be very unlucky for this to lead to anything more than mild amusement for all concerned. Using *spectacles* as I have, or *eyeglasses*, *specs*, etc. for one type and *drinking*/*wine*/*water* *glasses* for the other would soon avoid this, at the cost of using a less common or less idiomatic word.

Comment: I cannot think of a single variety of English where the pronunciation of *glasses* differs depending on whether they are *sun-*, *wine*, *opera*, *looking-*, or any other kind.

Comment: @choster me neither (whether the speaker says  /ɡlɑːs/ or /ɡlas/, they do the same whatever type and singular or plural), but I wanted to briefly specify the context in which I wrote the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just specify the type of glass/es in the future!